# IFrame Passing value

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an iframe issue. I have a page where I have a dial. On- click  the dial needle show me the value of an angle. Now I want to pass this value of angle from my dial.html page to my parent page on certain location..
I have tried below code. It gives me both dial and angle within the frame. I want to take this angle value and show it in different location. So how would I pull out this angle value from iframe to a different location in my parent page.

```
<iframe name="clkwise1" id="clkwise1" src="Dial1.htm" width=150 height=215 frameborder=0 scrolling="no" ></iframe>



function myAngle() {

    var iframeVal= document.getElementById('clkwise1').contentWindow;       
    document.getElementById("anglevalue").innerHTML = iframeVal;

   
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, please improve your question. Perhaps include some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the iframe's `document` and set a variable there:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('clkwise1').contentWindow;
iframe.clockAngle = localClockAngle;
```

Comment: where did you get localclockAngle.

Comment: It's whatever variable you've got that represents the value of the angle.